# Variable deleted when out of loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am making a code for register system for practice and I am having problem how to add a list of id and password.

```
print('id = ')
id = input()
while True:
    print('password = ')
    password = input()

    print('Please retype your password = ')
    repassword = input()

    if repassword == pas:
        print('successfully registered.')
        acc = [ ]
        acc.append([(id),(pas)])
        break
    else:
        print('please check your password.')
```

When this loop ends `acc` list get deleted and I can't use the list.
How can I save my list?

Comment: If you got to where `acc` was defined, it would stay defined outside the loop. And you don't need to make it a list, you can just say `acc = (id, password)`. But your code as posted would raise a `NameError` - `pas` is not defined. Perhaps this isn't exactly what you're running?

Comment: @Butee - are you trying to get one user ID and password from your code, or several? What does the surrounding code look like?

Answer (score 2):

I've made several changes to your code to get it to work:

1. Rename `pas` to `password`.
2. Instantiate `acc` at the beginning outside the loop, so it doesn't get cleared each loop.
3. Append a tuple to your list instead of a list.

Try this:

```
acc = []

print('id = ')
id = input()

while True:
    print('password = ')
    password = input()

    print('Please retype your password = ')
    repassword = input()

    if repassword == password:
        print('successfully registered.')
        acc.append((id, password))
        break
    else:
        print('please check your password.')

print(acc)
```

Comment: Moving `acc` outside the loop is unnecessary. Try it! I mention this only because suggesting it may confuse the asker's understanding of scope.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks, isn't the whole point that user should be able to repeatedly run the script and add multiple `(username, password)` combinations? if we reset `acc = []` each loop, you'll lose previously input data.

Comment: It's certainly not clear that that's the point. The asker doesn't say anything about that. And your code won't accomplish that either! How would another entry ever get added?

Comment: the idea is `acc = []` is called once and everything below is repeated multiple times. i haven't spelt it out, but can do if OP asks. why would you create a list just to hold one tuple?

Comment: Because you're confused about how scope works and you've seen examples using lists to hold a single result? I've seen a lot of that sort of thing. But I guess it's not clear without more input from the poster.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing stopping your code from working is that you call the password variable `password` in one place and `pas` in two other places. Doing nothing else but changing `pas` to `password` makes it work just fine.

Variables defined within a loop are still in scope when the loop exits. That's a fundamental part of how Python works. Here's a simple demonstration:

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Nov 13 2017, 09:55:42)
[GCC 4.9.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> while True:
...     x = 5
...     break
...
>>> x
5
```

There are three things I'd change about your code, however, besides fixing the misnamed variable:

- Use a different variable name for "id" - `id` is a built-in function, and it's not a good idea to [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) built-in functions. Call it "user_id", perhaps.
- Pass a prompt to `input` rather than printing it - this is just more concise. Like so:

  ```
  password = input("password = ")
  ```
- Assign `acc` as a simple tuple - it doesn't need to be a list, and you don't need to create it and then instantiate it. Just do

  ```
  if repassword == password:    
      acc = (user_id, password)
      break
  ```

  or, for that matter, simply use user_id and password after you've exited the `while` loop. You don't need `acc` at all!

With all these changes, your code becomes a bit shorter and simpler:

```
user_id = input('id = ')
while True:
    password = input('password = ')
    repassword = input('Please retype your password = ')

    if repassword == password:
        print('successfully registered.')
        break
    else:
        print('please check your password.')
print("User id: {}\nPassword: {}".format(user_id, password))
```